# Making native pages in Ionic 3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm making crossplatofrm app using Cordova and Ionic 3 for Android and iOS. I'm struggling with startup performance on older Android versions. My idea is to make some parts of the app native(in Java or Kotlin) for Android and normal Ionic/Cordova app for iOS so less Javascript should equal less startup time. Is this possible and if it is what is the best way to do it?

Comment: If you use `Ionic 3 latest` with `Angular 5` with `lazy loading` then you can achieve **almost native** performance on both platforms (`Android` and `ios`)

Comment: Startup time has been an issue with Hybrid apps. Either go full native or just ignore the laggy startup. I would not suggest mixing native with hybrid

Comment: @krv Unfortunetaly that is not an option. Startup time is about 12sec on Android 5.0 and below and that is unacceptable for client.

Comment: @Sampath I am using lazy loading already.

Comment: No matter what you do (lazy loading, crosswalk or webkit plugin, prod flags) there will be always the startup problem. Like @krv said it's an issue for hybrid apps.

Comment: You might want to look at NativeScript. I created a few apps using it. It had awesome performance but still had issues with startup time. This was almost a year ago. Maybe that is not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Make a fork of Splash plugin. 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

build & use in your App

Modify the Android implementation 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/src/android/SplashScreen.java

For older API levels manage hiding the splash, when user is done in the first screen. e.g. Login has happened & removeSplashScreen is called

```
splashDialog.dismiss();
```

have same functionality in Ionic for iOS platform. use 'platform' to check if you are in Android and set root of application differently.